# Не работает бегущая строка

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Делаю бегущую строку через swiper js, при slidesPerView: 3 она работает, а при большем количестве прокручивается до конца и останавливается.

```
 <section class="brands">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="brands__title"><?=$props['title']?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="brands__container swiper-carousel">
        <div class="brands__items swiper-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ($list as $image) :?>
                <div class="brands__item swiper-slide">
                    <img src="<?=$image['photo']?>" alt="" class="brands__photo">
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>



import Swiper from 'swiper';
import {Autoplay,FreeMode} from 'swiper/modules';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/autoplay';


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=> {
    let swiperBrands = new Swiper('.swiper-carousel', {
        slidesPerView: 5.5,
        spaceBetween: 40,
        modules: [Autoplay,FreeMode],
        speed: 2000,
        loop: true,

        freeMode:{
        enabled: true,
            momentumBounce: true
        },


    autoplay: {
            delay: 1,
            disableOnInteraction: false,

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Проблема, которую вы описываете, вероятно связана с тем, что бегущая строка прокручивается до конца и останавливается, потому что количество слайдов (slidesPerView) больше, чем фактическое количество слайдов. В вашем случае slidesPerView установлено на 5.5, но похоже, у вас всего несколько слайдов.

Comment: у меня 6 слайдов

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас всего 6 слайдов, и вы хотите, чтобы они отображались в бегущей строке, где одновременно видно 5.5 слайдов, вы можете установить slidesPerView равным 6 и добавить параметр loopedSlides с таким же значением:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let swiperBrands = new Swiper('.swiper-carousel', {
    slidesPerView: 6,
    spaceBetween: 40,
    loop: true,
    loopedSlides: 6, // Устанавливаем количество слайдов для бесконечного цикла

    modules: [Autoplay, FreeMode],
    speed: 2000,

    freeMode: {
      enabled: true,
      momentumBounce: true
    },

    autoplay: {
      delay: 1000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    }
  });
});
```

В этом случае, у вас будет бегущая строка из 6 слайдов, и она будет бесконечно циклироваться без остановки.

Comment: Только что попробовал, слайды так же останавливаются и все.

Comment: У  вас случайно нет CSS-стилей или других скриптов, которые могут вмешиваться в работу Swiper. Иногда проблема может быть связана с конфликтами стилей или другими скриптами на странице.

Comment: Если слайды останавливаются при увеличении slidesPerView, это может быть связано с тем, что вы устанавливаете слишком большое значение slidesPerView, которое не может быть умещено в доступной области. Попробуйте уменьшить значение slidesPerView до более разумного числа, которое помещается в вашей разметке.

Comment: стили есть, но я не думаю, что они как то конфликтуют, а на счет количества слайдов, работает только при 3

Comment: это может быть связано с ограничением вашего дизайна или с тем, что Swiper не может правильно обработать большее количество слайдов с вашей текущей разметкой и стилями. Если вы хотите использовать большее количество слайдов, вам может потребоваться пересмотреть ваш дизайн и разметку. Возможно, вам придется увеличить ширину контейнера, уменьшить размеры слайдов или применить другие стили, чтобы сделать их более компактными. Кроме того, убедитесь, что изображения в слайдерах не слишком большие, чтобы они могли правильно помещаться на экране.

Comment: В общем я разобрался, просто увеличил кол-во изображений в 2 раза.

Comment: Отлично, рад за Вас что получилось решить эту проблему!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь